# Restricting a Role's S3 Write Privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I would like to restrict my role from writing to unauthorized buckets in different accounts.  For example, I will have role A in account A.  S3 bucket B is created in account B and has a bucket policy allowing role A to write into it. I need a policy on role A/account A to prevent role A from being able to write into bucket B.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you verified that it is possible for a role to write to a bucket in the scenario you described?  Because it shouldn't be.  A permissive bucket policy in account B should not be sufficient to allow a principal in account A to write to the bucket unless account A provides a grant for the principal as well.

Comment: @BrunoReis your claim is inconsistent with Example #4 in the S3 documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-auth-workflow-bucket-operation.html).  Now, if the user has an S3 grant for "all" buckets then obviously that includes all buckets inside the account and all buckets outside the account that also allow access to the user... but you are suggesting that a user (role) with no S3 privileges in their own account can still access foreign buckets based solely on the foreign bucket policy.  That's directly contradicted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest *(from an IAM Policy perspective!)* way to achieve what you are looking for, while minimizing the risk of overlooking something and introducing a potential security problem, is to use Access Points.

You can create Access Points and associate them with your buckets. Then, instead of trying to interact with the bucket directly, you interact with the Access Point.

The reason this can help you is that there's an IAM Policy Condition Key available to test the Account ID that owns an Access Point. What you need to do, then, is simply add a statement to your IAM Role's Policy that will `"Effect": "Deny"` all S3 actions, on all resources, when the request matches a condition that tests `"StringNotEquals": { "s3:DataAccessPointAccount": "YOUR_ACCT_NUMBER" }`.

Note that you'll not be able to access any S3 resources without going through an Access Point. So **this will increase your initial setup complexity** (and the complexity of creating new buckets, since now you'll also need to create and associate an access point). It will also become **more complex to interact with S3**, since you'll now always need to go through the Access Point.

Those are trade-offs you'll need to accept if you want to implement a solution like this. But **it'll achieve your goal: it'll be *impossible* for this IAM Role to access S3 buckets outside of your account**.

Here's what the Policy would look like (tailor it to your specific needs):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyWithoutAccessPoint",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointAccount": "YOUR_AWS_ACCT_ID"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll also need to `Allow` any operations that you need.

---

If this trade-off (more complexity interacting with S3 for a completely straightforward IAM Policy) doesn't work for you, you'll need something different.

Keep in mind that **there's always a trade-off**.

---

**Alternative 1**

One alternative possibility is what @Marcin described: *explicitly deny* access to these buckets in the other accounts.

However, the trade-off here is that ***you'll never know*** what are *all* the S3 Buckets, owned by other AWS accounts, that granted access to your IAM Role.

So you can only deny access to the buckets you know about.

In a threat model in which the attacker wants to exfiltrate data from your account, they could create a new bucket *that you don't know about*, grant access to the IAM Role through a Bucket Policy on that new bucket, and then somehow make to role write into that newly created bucket.

Benefit: no changes to how your applications use S3.

Disadvantage: possible attack scenario since you can't know the entire list of buckets from other accounts that allow access to your role (i.e., you'd be blocking access "reactively", that is, only *after* something bad could have already happened).

---

**Alternative 2**

Another alternative is for you to instead create an IAM Policy that *explicitly denies access to* ***all buckets NOT enumerated in the policy***.

To implement this "negated list", you use `NotResource`, rather than the more common `Resource` policy element.

Here's what the policy would look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyWithoutAccessPoint",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "NotResource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-1",
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-1/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-2",
              "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Again, like in the other sample policy in this answer, remember that you'll still need to explicitly allow actions.

Benefit: you don't need to change the way you interact with S3, and you don't have to know the names of all buckets in other accounts that allow access to your IAM Role.

Disadvantage: you need to maintain this growing list of buckets. Also, keep in mind that there's a maximum policy size that you may eventually hit, making this solution limited in scale (although it can grow quite a lot).

Comment: Is there any way to check the owning account without using access points?

For instance, having some policy like @marcin provided but checking 
NotAccount: AWS_ACCT_ID

Comment: @MelissaGuo - Unfortunately, there's nothing like `Account` or `NotAccount` available as a condition key (otherwise, it would be the simplest solution, and exactly what you'd be looking for, instead of these solutions I listed above). There are more possibilities than the 3 above, but anything else that I can think of will dramatically increase complexity compared to anything I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @MelissaGuo — On a different note, in your question, you explained *what you want to do* (i.e., *"restrict my role from writing to unauthorized buckets in different accounts"*), and you're asking *how to implement* a solution that you thought about (which, as I explained above, is not directly possible, so you need something different that has trade-offs). But **what problem is that solution attempting to solve?** There may be better solutions for the actual underlying problem. It would be useful if you could describe what that underlying problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The problem I'm trying to address is bucket sniping.  In all cases, I want to ensure that the bucket I'm writing to is actually owned by my account.

Comment: @MelissaGuo — Ok, so it's truly a security concern, which I kinda assumed in my initial answer. My choice would definitely be the first solution I proposed: use access points, and configure the Role's policy to deny S3 actions not using an access point owned by your account. You'll then have to make the applications not refer to the bucket by its name, but rather by its access point (i.e., instead of storing some config variable saying `"bucket": "my-bucket"`, you'd use `"bucket": "arn:aws:s3:REGION:ACCT:accesspoint:AP-NAME"`). But then you get the security you need.

Comment: (the reason I'd discard the alternatives is security, which seems to be the main concern; with alt 1, you can't possibly know the names of all external buckets allowing access to your role; with alt 2, you have to keep updating IAM Policies for any new buckets you might need to allow access to, which has a limit, and I also tend to avoid solutions that require constant modifications of IAM Policy (they tend to indicate a poor design of policies)).

Comment: Do you happen to know if writing to access points are support using pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

By default buckets are private. But if you already have a bucket policy allowing a role in Account A to write to it and don't want to check the policy, you could add
an **explicit deny** to the role.

The deny would prohibit `s3::PutObject` on the bucket and its objects. This works [because](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html):

> an **explicit deny** in any of these policies **overrides the allow**.

En example of such a policy which could be added to the role in Account A is following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "deny-puts-to-bucket-in-acc-b",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                 "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-from-account-B>/*",
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This only denies `PutObject`. You may consider **other actions** as well such as `PutObjectAcl` or actions on the bucket itself and many more.

Nevertheless, the above policy should be a **good start** to tailor it to your specific requirements.